# Отправка формы React , axios , useForm

Tags: javascript, reactjs, form, axios

Нужно с помощью useForm создать форму где, допустим, 3 инпута, 2 типа текст (name и email) и 1 файл (photo). При нажатии на кнопку должен выполнятся POST запрос на url через axios с определенным заголовком (токеном). **Проблема в том, что в data у меня то что на фото ниже (photo length: 0), соответственно запрос не выполняется**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Проверяй key и другие причины пересоздания файлового инпута...

Comment: так у меня один файловый инпут который я создал вручную без перебора

Comment: Тем не менее может пересоздаваться родитель или что-то ещё.